# How to update Nested object in array -react

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to update the properties (array of objects).
I have to update the complete object with new given object

writing an test case in which i need to update specific prop1.B values to prop2 values but i am not able to do this

```
const prop1 = {
mainList:{
list1:[{...}],
list2:[{...}],
list3:[...]
  }
}
```

to

```
const prop2 = {
list2:[{...}],
}
```

**i want to update prop1.mainList.list2 values to prop2.list2 values**

My work around on this issue

```
   const { output } = renderList({...prop1,...prop1.mainList.list2,...prop2,...prop2.list2})
```

list2 is not updating

Comment: I don't think I understand the question fully, but I suspect you might want something like `{...prop1, mainList: { ...prop1.mainList, ...prop2}}` or even simply `{mainList: { ...prop1.mainList, ...prop2}}`

Comment: @StevenFrew i want to upate prop1.mainList.list2 values to prop2.list2 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to update `prop1.mainList.list2` with the contents of `prop2.list2`? If so, you can do something like this:

```js
{mainList: {...prop1.mainList, ...prop2}}
```

And if you want to add the contents of `prop2.list2` to `prop1.mainList.list2` you can do:

```js
{mainList: {...prop1.mainList, list2: [...prop1.mainList.list2, ...prop2.list2]}}
```

A tip: for updating nested element like this one, use something like [ImmerJS](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/). It'll make your life way easier.

Comment: it's throwing me TypeError: this.prop1.mainList.List2 is not iterable

Comment: Is `this.prop1.mainList.List2` an array or an object? if it's an array destructure it inside an array, if it's an object destructure it inside an object. And don't forget to check if list2 is undefined/null.